# How to create cakephp database config settings (login, password) dynamically

Tags: database, cakephp, dynamic, settings, config

Every cakephp user will have his database(Postgres) user replica. Therefore when he logs in, the database default config must take the "login" and "password" sent in the login.ctp form and with those values create the DATABASE_CONFIG. So far I have this, but I can't figure it out how to pass variables to the constructor. Is it possible? Is there an alternative?. Please help.

```
    enter code here
class DATABASE_CONFIG{
        var $default = array(
            'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'login' => 'XXX',
            'password' => 'YYY',
            'database' => 'db1',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema'=>'public'
            //'encoding' => 'utf8',
            );
    function __construct(){
        $this->default['login'] = $userSentFromForm;
        $this->default['password'] = $passwordSentFromForm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you have a different database connection for every user? :/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have some global database with users which stores login information (username and hashsed password) so you can validate & login user.

When user logs-in you save data from that form into the session.

Then you redirect the user to some action, like /dashboard or any else. Following request will have your desired data in session object, so you can read it in `DATBASE_CONFIG::__construct()`.